Identify this wide sans serif font, similar to Montserrat
I am looking for this wide sans serif font for almost a year, yet I still haven't found it.
It is very similar to the Montserrat font, but it has minor changes to the characters.
This is what it looks like:

Can anyone help me find this font.

It might be Marsden Wide Semi Bold.
But what do you need it for? Marsden Wide Semi Bold is a premium commercial font while Montserrat you can find around for free, the differences are so close to unnoticeable if I were you I would use Montserrat.

It looks like Montserrat Bold.
It's free to use under the SIL Open Font License, Version 1.1.
